# Error show during compile time: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am getting an error with a single listing page or detailed page.
It shows the method [] was called on null.
But is as defined some itemData in main dart file it also showa same error. please help me to solve this error.

this is my DetailPage.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/custom/BorderIcon.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/custom/OptionButton.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/utils/custom_functions.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/utils/widget_functions.dart';


class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {

final dynamic itemData;

const DetailPage({super.key, @required this.itemData});
 //DetailPage({Key? key,@required this.itemData}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
 final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
 final double padding = 25;
 final sidePadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding);
 return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: COLOR_WHITE,
      body: Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(itemData["image"]),
                  Positioned(
                    width: size.width,
                    top: padding,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: sidePadding,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: BorderIcon(
                            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.keyboard_backspace, color:COLOR_BLACK,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        BorderIcon(
                            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                            child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: COLOR_BLACK),
                        ),
                      ],
                     ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ],
                  ),
                  addVerticalSpace(padding),
                  Padding(
                      padding: sidePadding,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                        Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                            Text("${formatCurrency(itemData["amount"])}",style: themeData.textTheme.headline1,),
                            addVerticalSpace(5),
                            Text("\$${itemData["address"]}",style: themeData.textTheme.subtitle2,),
                            ]
                          ),
                          BorderIcon(
                            width: 0,
                            height: 0,
                            child: Text("20 Hours ago",style: themeData.textTheme.headline5,),padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15,horizontal: 15),
                          )
                        ],
                     ),
                  ),
                  addVerticalSpace(padding),
                  Padding(
                      padding: sidePadding,
                      child: Text("House Information",style: themeData.textTheme.headline4,),
                  ),
                  addVerticalSpace(padding),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        InformationTile(content: "${itemData["area"]}",name: "Square Foot",),
                        InformationTile(content: "${itemData["bedrooms"]}",name: "Bedrooms",),
                        InformationTile(content: "${itemData["bathrooms"]}",name: "Bathrooms",),
                        InformationTile(content: "${itemData["garage"]}",name: "Garage",)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  addVerticalSpace(padding),
                  Padding(
                      padding: sidePadding,
                      child: Text(
                        itemData["description"],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        style: themeData.textTheme.bodyText2,
                      ),
                  ),
                  addVerticalSpace(200),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 20,
                width: size.width,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    OptionButton(text: "Message",icon: Icons.message,width: size.width*0.35,),
                    addHorizontalSpace(10),
                    OptionButton(text: "Call",icon: Icons.call,width: size.width*0.35,),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
);
}
}

class InformationTile extends StatelessWidget{

final String content;
final String name;

const InformationTile({super.key, required this.content, required this.name});


@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
 final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 final double tileSize = size.width*0.20;
 return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      BorderIcon(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          width: tileSize,
          height: tileSize,
          child: Text(content,style: themeData.textTheme.headline3,)),
      addVerticalSpace(15),
      Text(name,style: themeData.textTheme.headline6,)
    ],
  ),
);

}

}
```

this is my Sample_data.dart file
[in this file i add some sample data in json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQKB0.png)

and this is how i define my DetailPage file in main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/screens/LandingPage.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/screens/DetailPage.dart';
import 'package:uidesign/utils/constants.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double screenWidth = window.physicalSize.width;
  return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Design 1',
  theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: COLOR_WHITE, accentColor: COLOR_DARK_BLUE, textTheme: screenWidth < 500 ? TEXT_THEME_SMALL : TEXT_THEME_DEFAULT, fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
  //home: LandingPage(),
  //home: DetailPage(itemData: 1),
  home: const DetailPage(),
);
}
}
```

error in terminal: [the line i select on terminal is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDGB9.png)
Please help me out how it get the data with the key

Comment: Image.asset(itemData["image"]) ---- this is where the error happens. It is because itemData is null. Probably when you are navigating to DetailsPage, you are not sending itemData to details Page. The following code is wrong: home: const DetailPage(), you are not passing itemData here. So it is always null

Answer (score 0):

Pass your RE_DATA list here in MainScreen

```
home: DetailPage(itemData: RE_DATA)
```

And Change `List<dynamic> itemData` to `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` itemData in DetailPage.

You are getting list so access itemData like this `itemData[index]['image']`

If possible use model for your RE_DATA instead of passing List of Maps.